# Simplifying $\sum_{ m = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{-am^2/2 + bm}$

Tags: summation

Is there any way to simplify an expression like this $\sum_{ m = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{-am^2/2 + bm}$? I know there exist an identity for a similar expression, just integrating, does the same identity still hold for the summation case? If so, how can I argue that the identity still holds. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that such sum has no known closed form leads to defining the [*Jacobi theta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function).

Comment: The fact that an integral has a closed form, doesn't mean the related sum does.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you mean by "simplify". The summation is equal to $f(e^{b-a/2},e^{-b-a/2})$ where $f(,)$ is [Ramanujan's general theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanThetaFunctions.html). I don't know what identity you are referring to.